# Are CRISPR patents actual device or merely methods that utilizing devices?

Tags: chemistry-microbiology, crispr

I've been reading a little about this case and reviewing the claims in the [Charpentier application](https://www.google.com/patents/EP3071695A2?dq=Charpentier%20CRISPR&cl=en) and the [Zhang grant](https://www.google.com/patents/US8697359).  Biotech patents are not an area where I have much knowledge, but I have great interest in what constitutes "abstract" in a patent context, both in the US and Internationally.

In my initial review, it seems as though the patent grant and application referenced methods, CRISPR "techniques", as opposed to actual machines.  Is this correct?

Comment: Are you suggesting that only machines are patentable? Please link the patents you are referring to to make it easier to review.

Comment: @EricShain Precisely the opposite.  My personal interest is in the patentability of novel game mechanics, particularly fundamental mechanics that require a gameboard that processes to be commercialized.  I'm trying to learn more about CRISPR because, if it is merely a set of methods that require a device, that would be quite similar to the type of game patents I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both cited documents have method claims. I see references to proteins, but not specific apparatus.